# axios post user to userProfile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

So, I Have:

**UserProfile:**

```py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile', unique=False)
    orders = models.ManyToManyField(Order, blank=True)
```

**Order:**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    car_brand = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    car_model = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    repair_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

**Register.js:**

```
...
// Handling the form submission
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (name === '' || email === '' || password === '') {
            setError(true);
        } else {


            console.log('component Register registering ')


            let user = {
                username: name,
                email: email,
                password: password,
                is_active: false,
            }


            axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/users/', {
                username: name,
                email: email,
                password: password,
                is_active: false,
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error.response);
                });

            axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/profiles/', {
                user: null,
                orders: []
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error.response);
                });


            setSubmitted(true);
            setError(false);
        }
    };
...
```

Question is:

User creation works fine, its create the user, it shows at the rest-api, and .db

How to create UserProfile? How I can add user, which I created first, and the add empty orders list??

Comment: Did you create serializer for `UserProfile`?

Comment: @DavidLu Yeah.
`class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
model = UserProfile
fields = ['user', 'orders']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set the `OrderSerializer` in the `UserProfileSerializer`.

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    orders = OrderSerializer(many = True)
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only = True)
    user = UserSerializer(read_only = True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['user', 'orders', 'user_id']
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        order_ids = []
        order_data = validated_data.pop('orders')
        for order_item in order_data:
            new_order = Order.objects.create(**order_item)
            order_ids.append(new_order.id)
        new_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user_id = validated_data['user_id'])
        new_profile.set(order_ids)
        return new_profile
```

Then in post API, you need to upload user_id and orders like the following. Here I assume user has already been created and orders need to be created.

```
{
    "user_id": 1,
    "orders": [
        {
            "car_brand": "...",
            "car_model": "...",
            "repair_type": "..."
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Of course, you can create user when create user profile, but in order to do that, you can change a code little bit.